# How to Make Two Floating Action Buttons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a counter app with one floating action button.

If I want to add one more button to reset the counter,  where can I add a second floating action button at the bottom bar?

Also, i have to add any method in the void section or is there any reset counter function available?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Counter App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Counter App'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('You have pressed the button $_counter times.'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 50.0,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          _counter++;
            }),
        tooltip: 'Increment Counter',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You want use FAB or Button inside bottom bar?

Comment: Want to use FAB only, it is not necessary to use in bottom bar.

Comment: You want two or more FAB buttons ok?

Comment: only two FAB buttons

Comment: See answer below..

Comment: "The material design specification recommends only using one floating action button per screen." - [Source](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton/heroTag.html). Maybe worth using `persistentFooterButtons` instead?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the **flutter_speed_dial** package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_speed_dial

On the link above have a example showing how to use it. You must use `SpeedDial` class and on `children[]` you can add some buttons with `SpeedDialChild`. The sample below shows 2 FABs.

Example using it:

```
Widget _getFAB() {
        return SpeedDial(
          animatedIcon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
          animatedIconTheme: IconThemeData(size: 22),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
          visible: true,
          curve: Curves.bounceIn,
          children: [
                // FAB 1
                SpeedDialChild(
                child: Icon(Icons.assignment_turned_in),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
                onTap: () { /* do anything */ },
                label: 'Button 1',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0),
                labelBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF801E48)),
                // FAB 2
                SpeedDialChild(
                child: Icon(Icons.assignment_turned_in),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFF801E48),
                onTap: () {
                   setState(() {
                      _counter = 0;
                   });
                },
                label: 'Button 2',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0),
                labelBackgroundColor: Color(0xFF801E48))
          ],
        );
  }
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you help me what to write in " onTap: () {}, label: 'Button 2'," to reset the counter?

Comment: is it possible to have 2 FABs horizontally aligned in the bottom right of the screen without having the unfolding functionality of the speed dial widget? (i.e. so that both FABs are displayed permanently)

Comment: @Augusto your answer is correct, there is a syntax error. Just add ); to close the setState correctly.

Comment: @Rich Steinmetz, look up the answer by RaZzLe and try with Row instead of Column

Comment: perfect simple example, better then the one they have in their pub.dev site, just one note: add this `_getFAB()` result to the `Scaffold`'s `floatingActionButton` attribute, like this: `floatingActionButton: _getFAB(),`

Answer (score 80):

`floatingActionButton` property on `Scaffold` widget do not need to take `FloatingActionButton` widget necessarily. It can also take `Column` or `Row` widgets.

Below, I'm sharing my Scaffold widget example with two floating action buttons on top of each other.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(""),
  ),
  body: SingleChildScrollView(/*...*/),
  floatingActionButton: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: [
      FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          //...
        },
        heroTag: null,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 10,
      ),
      FloatingActionButton(           
        child: Icon(
          Icons.star
        ),
        onPressed: () => _someFunc(),
        heroTag: null,
      )
    ]
  )
);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what that ```heroTag: null``` means, I'm a bit confused about it?

Comment: `heroTag` is the tag to apply to the button's `Hero` widget. By default Flutter assumes that there should be only one `FloatingActionButton` per screen, and if one uses more than one FloatingActionButton on a screen then heroTags must be set explicitly. On above example I set them ´null´ as I didn't use any animations on those buttons. You can be set something like `heroTag: "heroTag1"` and on the other FloatingActionButton like `heroTag: "heroTag2"` if you are using Animations.
For more details check this link:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html

Comment: in flutter documentation, we can use most in action buttons per screen.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, It's worked..!

```dart
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: Icon(Icons.navigate_before_rounded),
            heroTag: "fab1",
          ),
          FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () => {},
            child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next_rounded),
            heroTag: "fab2",
          ),
        ]
      )
```

[image: two FloatingActionButton at bottom-right]

Comment: `Error : multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree`

Comment: could you please share your code?
OR checkout full code [here](https://github.com/sachinchillal/res/blob/main/flutter/view_content.dart#L67)
maybe you need to add **heroTag: "fab1",** & **heroTag: "fab2",** to each FloatingActionButton

Comment: in flutter documentation, we can use most in action buttons per screen

Comment: No way to add padding here, they touch each other awkwardly.

Answer (score 6):

According to [medium post](https://medium.com/@kaendagger/test-cef30fcb5c54)

You can use Column (for vertical alignment) or Row widget (for horizontal alignment) with 2 FAB as children and just set hero Tag null or assign diffent HeroTags.

Answer (score 6):

You can make it by setup "heroTag: null" as below:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
             ...),
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: null,
             ...),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: in flutter documentation, we can use most in action buttons per screen

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with this, also to add space between the buttons you can add a width and the 'hero' tags are very important.

```html
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                heroTag: "btn",
                onPressed: () => _speak(textEditingController.text),
                child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 40,
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                heroTag: "btn2",
                onPressed: () => _stop(),
                child: Icon(Icons.stop),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rahnx.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter Documentation, we can use at most one floating action button on a single screen. We can do it using RawMaterialButton() widget. This widget parent widget of the floating action button

It's something like that

```html
  class RoundIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
      const RoundIconButton({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return RawMaterialButton(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 40, minWidth: 40),
          shape: CircleBorder(),
          fillColor: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text("+"),
        );
      }
    }
class Fab extends StatelessWidget {
  const Fab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        RawMaterialButton(),
        RawMaterialButton(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```